# Idiom in python for opening second file when the first file does not exist

Tags: python, file-io

I want to write a script which checks and opens a settings-file called ".mysettings" if it exists in the HOME-directory. If the file is not present in the HOME-directory it should try to open one in the current directory if it exists there.

Is there a idiom or a one-liner in python to program something like that?

The best way I can think of right now is to try to open the first file with a try-catch block like explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-using-python) and then trying the second file.

Comment: Yes, one-liners do exist, and there are already answers to your question below that show you how to do that; however, any solution that checks for file existence and later opens it is not secure, as is described in the answers to the very question you linked to.

Comment: Any reason why you have to use a one-liner, instead of the more readable `try... except` blocs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the python way to do it.  No one liner, but clear, and easy to read.

```
try:
    with open("/tmp/foo.txt") as foo:
        print foo.read()
except:
    try:
        with open("./foo.txt") as foo:
            print foo.read()
    except:
        print "No foo'ing files!"
```

Of course, you could always do something like this as well:

```
for f in ["/tmp/foo.txt", "./foo.txt"]:
    try:
        foo = open(f)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        print foo.read()
```

- Beautiful is better than ugly.
- Readability counts.

Comment: I agree. Readability is more important than brevity, and it's pretty  obvious what's going on in the above code.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
f = open(fn1 if os.path.exists(fn1) else fn2, "r")
```

(Though it is not exactly same as try/catch, because there are rare situations when it may still throw when fn1 existed at the time of checking.)

Comment: +1 for answering the question as asked _and_ giving the disclaimer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  `If the file is not present in the HOME-directory it should try to open one in the current directory if it exists there.`  This will try to open fn2 if fn1 doesn't exist regardless of whether it exists or not and will raise if it doesn't.

Comment: @sberry He didn't say what shall happen if fn2 doesn't exist. He made it clear he is able to code a trivial try/catch himself; he's looking for shorter code, and here it is.

Comment: If you go by the title, the "idiom"  in python _is_ to use `try... except`.  +1 but I'd like to see a reference to the "pythonic"  way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
filename = '/tmp/x1' if os.path.exists('/tmp/x1') else '/tmp/x2'
```